# AppYet use custom query

Tags: android, sql, mobile

I'm trying to build a mobile app based using frameworks and I have use [AppYet](http://appyet.com) to build it. It almost has all the needs to turn my site into news feed app.

Now, according to AppYet we can use query like `PubDate > [NOW] - 86400000 AND IsDeleted = 0` to create news feed of 24 hours, I would like to integrate this on my app.So, I changed the query to `date > [NOW] -86400000` since date is my field for my news list in database. But it doesn't work (the app kept showing loading circles).

My question is how does AppYet query works? How does it select our database tables? Is it using the same database engine like my web does (the web uses MySQL database). So far there's no clear documentation on this, I wonder if anyone can point me to it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

PubDate is the name of the field they use on the cache database inside the app.
It is taken from the  field of your RSS feed

You should keep the code as in the example they provide and make sure your RSS is well-formed.
You can check it here:

http://validator.w3.org/feed/